# local and remote branch need to match names for git push?

Tags: git, github

It'd be awesome if someone helped me get this.

Say I'm working in master or in a branch called MyBranch and I want to push the changes I just committed to a new github branch. When I do

```
git push origin RemoteBranch
```

it'll say something like

```
error: src refspec RemoteBranch does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:bla/bla.git'
```

1) Why is that? It seems that only way to replicate a commit to a remote branch is to make absolutely sure that their names are a perfect match. Basically I have to locally perform a git branch RemoteBranch, and then I can do a push just fine.

2) How can I see the full list of remote branches?

```
git branch -a
```

or

```
git branch -r
```

will only show the branches whose match I have on my local repo as opposed to all of the branches available on github.

Thank you!

Comment: have a look in your .git/config file to see what remote branch names your branches push to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you would have a look at the `man` page, you would find out how.

You could use: `git push <remote> <local-branch>:<remote-branch>`

Answer (score 2):

You must first create the local branch before you can push it:

```
git checkout -b RemoteBranch
git push -u origin RemoteBranch
```

The `-u` option is to automatically setup *RemoteBranch* to track *origin/RemoteBranch*

Or, if you are on master and would like to push up master as a new branch:

```
git push origin master:RemoteBranch
```